# C++: Runtime error in while loop condition

Tags: c++, while-loop, multiple-conditions

nums is a vector, and I have one code line that

```
while(i < nums.size()-2 && nums[i] == nums[i+1]) i++;
```

It would give me a Runtime error, If I run the code when the nums.size() is 1.
But if I change this line to:

```
while(i-2 < nums.size() && nums[i] == nums[i+1]) i++;
```

The build succeeds.

I have no idea, what is the difference in executing these two code line, and why does the build behave differently?

Does anyone has any idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sums.size()` returns an `unsigned` type so, if it has a value of `1`, `nums.size()-2`  gives a result equal to the maximum value that type can represent.   All built in unsigned types work that way.   Add a check of `nums.size() > 1` to your loop condition.   Assuming `i` is of type `int`, you're getting lucky that the second one doesn't (seem to) cause a problem, it can access past the end of `nums` (undefined behaviour).   One of the joys of undefined behaviour is that it can APPEAR to work.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for the quick reply. I didn't realize the return unsigend type of sums.size(). The question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::vector<>.size()` returns an `unsigned long` which, when combined with `nums.size() - 2` gives an underflow and the result is some really big number which doesn't fit your code logic. Since the expression `i < nums.size() - 2` will always evaluate to `true` because of the underflow, you will keep iterating through the vector until you reach index greater than it's size, which will cause runtime error, more specifically `vector index out of range`.